# Problem with getting remaining time of a pending local notification in swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am able to get the "time interval" but not the remaining time. Here is my code and the corresponding output. I have setup a local notification to be delivered in 10 minutes (600 seconds). However the time remaining is always shows as 10 minutes as well (even when there is only a few seconds remaining). Appreciate any comments:

---

### code

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
    for request in requests {
        let trigger = request.trigger  as! UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
        let interval = trigger.timeInterval
        let end = trigger.nextTriggerDate()!.timeIntervalSinceNow

        print("Notification time interval: \(interval)")
        print("Notification time remained: \(end)")
    }
})
```

---

### Output

Notification time interval: 600.0

Notification time remained: 599.99998

Comment: I ended up having to work around this by saving the submit time in userInfo part of the request. Then when I later on retrieve the request, I get the submit time from the userInfo and this way I can calculate when the trigger will fire.